# How can I subset a dataframe to get a series of smaller dataframes?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset, tidyverse

I have a large dataframe that has all of the data for the project I am working on and I am trying to produce a series of smaller dataframes that contain data that match for two columns. So for example for the example data below, I need to write a piece of script that produces a series of data frames for datapoints where year and colony are the same (e.g. year = 2012, colony = A; year = 2012, colony = B).

```
year <- c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014)
colony <- c ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
measurement <- c(4,6,1,4,8,2,1,5,4,1,3,8)
data <- data.frame(year, colony, measurement)
```

At the moment the best I can do is producing each individually:

```
A2012 <- filter(data, colony == 'A' & year == 2012)
B2012 <- filter(data, colony == 'B' & year == 2013)
```

etc. 
However, there are about 80 dataframes to produce so it would be better to automate this if possible. 
Does anyone know a way that I could do this quicker?

Comment: `myDfList <- split(df, interaction(df$colony, df$year))` will result in a list of data.frames specified as you mentioned. See gregor's answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for tips on working with such objects.

Comment: @lmo amazing! Thanks so much

Comment: Nice, did not know about the interaction function.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine functions `group_by` and `group_split` from dplyr to split the dataframe into a list of smaller dataframes:

```
data %>% 
  tibble() %>%
  group_by(colony,year) %>%
  group_split()

## <list_of<
##   tbl_df<
##     year       : double
##     colony     : character
##     measurement: double
##   >
## >[6]>
## [[1]]
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##    year colony measurement
##   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
## 1  2012 A                4
## 2  2012 A                6
## 
## [[2]]
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##    year colony measurement
##   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
## 1  2013 A                8
## 2  2013 A                2
##
## (...)
```

You may also want to look at the family of functions [group_map](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html), which allow you to apply a function to each group as if they were individual dataframes.